# pgfplots: How to set xticklabel as two line?

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ticks, dateplot

I want to design `xticklabels` as two line texts:

- First line: Date, e.g. `\month`/`\day`
- Second line: Time, e.g. `\hour`:`\minute`

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;                   Value
    2019-04-01 12:00:00;    1
    2019-04-02 12:00:00;    2
    2019-04-03 12:00:00;    3
    2019-04-04 12:00:00;    4
    2019-04-05 12:00:00;    5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
                     xticklabel         = \month/\day,
                     table/col sep      = semicolon]
                     \addplot table[x=Date,y=Value]{data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

---

The final question is: How to do so?

It seems that

- `xticklabel = \month/\day \\ \hour:\minute`

as well as

- `xticklabel = \month/\day \newline \hour:\minute`

does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The labels are Ti*k*Z nodes, so if you want it to be multiline, you must set option allowing it to do so.

```
\documentclass[margin=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;                   Value
    2019-04-01 12:00:00;    1
    2019-04-02 12:00:00;    2
    2019-04-03 12:00:00;    3
    2019-04-04 12:00:00;    4
    2019-04-05 12:00:00;    5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
                     xticklabel         = \month/\day\\xyzt,
                     xticklabel style   = {align=center},
                     table/col sep      = semicolon]
                     \addplot table[x=Date,y=Value]{data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]